# How to replace white with transparent in outside of block?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to replace the white color in my image with transparency. But when I use `-transparent white`, it removes the white colours everywhere. Is it possible to replace the white with transparency only outside the region of the green block? For example, here:

[image]

My current command is:

```
magick in.png -flatten -fuzz 5% -trim +repage -transparent white out.png
```

Answer (score 1):

It may need adjustment of the fuzz value, but do a transparent flood fill in ImageMagick will do what you want.

```
magick in.png -fuzz 5% -fill none -draw "alpha 30,30 floodfill" result.png
```

[image]